# How to change node colors of cohesive blocks?

Tags: plot, colors, attributes, nodes, social-networking

I'm trying to change the node colors in a particular graph, but the `V(gsna)$color` command doesn't work. For some reason, I can change shapes, but not colors. Specifically, I want to change the colors of nodes that occupy each cohesive block. The default colors don't read well in black and white print.

The dataset, *sna*, is a 2-mode, asymmetric incidence matrix. Here's an example (in reality, the dataset is much larger):

```
       Attr1    Attr2    Attr3    Attr4    Attr5
Subj1    1       0         0       1         1
Subj2    1       0         0       1         1
Subj3    1       0         1       0         1
Subj4    1       0         0       1         1
Subj5    0       1         0       0         0
Subj6    0       1         1       0         0
```

I used the cohesive.blocks() command to create hierarchically nested blocks. Subjects are represented by circles, attributes are represented by squares. 
Here is my code:

```
library(igraph)
as.matrix(sna) -> sna

gsna <- graph.incidence(sna)
bloc <- cohesive.blocks(gsna)

par(mar=c(.05,.05,.05,.05),cex=.8)
V(gsna)[V(gsna)$type == 1]$shape <- "square"
V(gsna)[V(gsna)$type == 0]$shape <- "circle"
plot(bloc,gsna,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold,vertex.size=5,edge.color="gray40",
 vertex.label.color="black",mark.groups=blocks(bloc))
```

I also tried using `vcol <- colorRampPalette(c("red4","green","aliceblue"))` and adding the `vertex.color=vcol` option to the plot() function, but that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank Professor Ronald Breiger for answering this question in person.

The solution is as follows:

```
group1 <- bloc$blocks[[1]]
a <- V(gsna)[group1]$color <- rep("blue4", length(group1))
group2 <- bloc$blocks[[2]]
b <- V(gsna)[group2]$color <- rep("deeppink", length(group2))
group3 <- bloc$blocks[[3]]
c <- V(gsna)[group3]$color <- rep("greenyellow", length(group3))

plot(gsna,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold,vertex.size=5,edge.color="gray40",
vertex.label.color="black",vertex.color=V(gsna)$color,mark.groups=blocks(bloc))
```

The `rep()` command is used to replicate a particular color (e.g., blue) for each element of a block (e.g., group1). Be sure to specify the color for each block AND the length of the block. If you leave out the length, it will not color all of the nodes in the block.

The order of the commands is important in this case because there are hierarchical clusters. Colors should be assigned in order from largest (in this case, blocks[[1]]) to smallest (blcoks[[3]]).

In the plot command, it is sufficient to input `V(gsna)$color`.